# HDI: Capture specific content types in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, sniffing

I've been tasked to audit in/outbound traffic at our site, but I don't know much about Wireshark.  I understand how to set up a capture filter for broad protocols (IP only or tcp, udp, icmp, etc), but how do I set it up so it only captures specific CONTENT types?  For example:

-ignore network chatter (dns/icmp/handshakes/etc)
-Image files (jpg/gif/png), audio (mp3), video (lots of types), archives (rar/zip/tar)
-Pages & sessions
-IMs

Comment: If I understand you right you are taking about capturing HTTP connections and inside only specific content types, right?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the capture filter does not allow such fine granular filtering options. But you can filter the captured connections afterwards.

But I think for you a HTTP proxy based solution like WebScarab, BurpSuite or Fiddler would be better as they are specialized in HTTP traffic.